# Addition of two numbers not working without ng model

Tags: angularjs, angular9

I want to add numbers without ng model attribute. I tried below but it does not work. Any suggestions please..

```
   First Number : <input type="number" class="form-control" id="firstNumber" >
    
    Last Number: <input type="number" class="form-control" id="secondNumber" >
    
    Total : {{firstNumber.value + secondNumber.Value}}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you not want to use ng-model when it is how angularjs binds to form controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should use "ng-model" directive. Attribute id has no relation to show value.

```
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="firstNumber" ng-model="firstNumber.value">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="secondNumber" ng-model="secondNumber.value">
  <h1>sum {{firstNumber.value + secondNumber.value}}</h1>
```

JS Fiddle:[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/redpeaks/0nm29f3j/11/)